# As One User, Using Multiple computers for Github

Tags: github

What is the best process for using multiple computers with one repository on Github, for one user?

Comment: Setup the same email address on each computer. And if needed tie multiple ssh keys to your github account.

Comment: Setup the same email address for git on the command line on each computer? then add another ssh key to my git account?

Comment: Yep! You want the same email as you are the same person making commits on both computers. You could have multiple emails, but you'd just want to tie both emails to your github account.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ssh-keys uploaded to you account. One on each different computer you use. That way you can remove access for any computer if it is compromised.